# Laravel 5.3 Passport Custom Grants?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I know I am not the only person who has come up to this point. Does anyone know how to **properly** implement a custom grant in Laravel(5.3) Passport?

Or

Have a good link/tutorial to reference how to properly do it?

I know there's this package:

https://github.com/mikemclin/passport-custom-request-grant

But I'm asking for a more "Do it yourself" approach.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about using the built in token scoping?

Comment: Scopes are more user specific or client specific. When it comes to doing a custom grant you gain the flexibility of changing the auth process flow or validation flow within auth to something that suits your authentication server's specific needs (whatever they may be).

Comment: The above package was made by "Do it yourself" approach already. Personal opinion, it is one of the best ways to implement this type requirement. Do not re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 8):

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Auth\Grants\FacebookGrant;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Passport\Bridge\RefreshTokenRepository;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
use League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        app(AuthorizationServer::class)->enableGrantType(
            $this->makeFacebookGrant(), Passport::tokensExpireIn()
        );

        Passport::routes();

        //
    }

    /**
     * Create and configure a Facebook grant instance.
     *
     * @return FacebookGrant
     */
    protected function makeFacebookGrant()
    {
        $grant = new FacebookGrant(
            $this->app->make(RefreshTokenRepository::class)
        );

        $grant->setRefreshTokenTTL(Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn());

        return $grant;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
sorry for only posting this code, i do not know how much this code is going to be useful to you.

Well, here i'll leave my implementation of FacebookGrant, hope this helps someone.

```
<?php

namespace App\Auth\Grants;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Passport\Bridge\User;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Entities\ClientEntityInterface;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Entities\UserEntityInterface;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\AbstractGrant;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Repositories\RefreshTokenRepositoryInterface;
use League\OAuth2\Server\RequestEvent;
use League\OAuth2\Server\ResponseTypes\ResponseTypeInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use RuntimeException;

class FacebookGrant extends AbstractGrant
{
    /**
     * @param RefreshTokenRepositoryInterface $refreshTokenRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        RefreshTokenRepositoryInterface $refreshTokenRepository
    ) {
        $this->setRefreshTokenRepository($refreshTokenRepository);

        $this->refreshTokenTTL = new \DateInterval('P1M');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function respondToAccessTokenRequest(
        ServerRequestInterface $request,
        ResponseTypeInterface $responseType,
        \DateInterval $accessTokenTTL
    ) {
        // Validate request
        $client = $this->validateClient($request);
        $scopes = $this->validateScopes($this->getRequestParameter('scope', $request));
        $user = $this->validateUser($request, $client);

        // Finalize the requested scopes
        $scopes = $this->scopeRepository->finalizeScopes($scopes, $this->getIdentifier(), $client, $user->getIdentifier());

        // Issue and persist new tokens
        $accessToken = $this->issueAccessToken($accessTokenTTL, $client, $user->getIdentifier(), $scopes);
        $refreshToken = $this->issueRefreshToken($accessToken);

        // Inject tokens into response
        $responseType->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        $responseType->setRefreshToken($refreshToken);

        return $responseType;
    }

    /**
     * @param ServerRequestInterface $request
     *
     * @return UserEntityInterface
     * @throws OAuthServerException
     */
    protected function validateUser(ServerRequestInterface $request, ClientEntityInterface $client)
    {
        $facebookId = $this->getRequestParameter('facebook_id', $request);
        if (is_null($facebookId)) {
            throw OAuthServerException::invalidRequest('facebook_id');
        }

        $email = $this->getRequestParameter('email', $request);
        if (is_null($email)) {
            throw OAuthServerException::invalidRequest('email');
        }

        $user = $this->getUserEntityByUserFacebookId(
            $facebookId,
            $email,
            $this->getIdentifier(),
            $client
        );

        if ($user instanceof UserEntityInterface === false) {
            $this->getEmitter()->emit(new RequestEvent(RequestEvent::USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED, $request));

            throw OAuthServerException::invalidCredentials();
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     *  Retrieve a user by the given Facebook Id.
     *
     * @param string  $facebookId
     * @param string  $email
     * @param string  $grantType
     * @param \League\OAuth2\Server\Entities\ClientEntityInterface  $clientEntity
     *
     * @return \Laravel\Passport\Bridge\User|null
     * @throws \League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException
     */
    private function getUserEntityByUserFacebookId($facebookId, $email, $grantType, ClientEntityInterface $clientEntity)
    {
        $provider = config('auth.guards.api.provider');

        if (is_null($model = config('auth.providers.'.$provider.'.model'))) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Unable to determine authentication model from configuration.');
        }

        $user = (new $model)->where('facebook_id', $facebookId)->first();

        if (is_null($user)) {
            $user = (new $model)->where('email', $email)->first();

            if (is_null($user)) {
                return;
            }

            // Now that we retrieved the user with the email, we need to update it with
            // the given facebook id. So the user account will be linked correctly.
            $user->facebook_id = $facebookId;
            $user->save();
        }

        return new User($user->getAuthIdentifier());
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getIdentifier()
    {
        return 'facebook';
    }
}
```

Comment: What about App\Auth\Grants\FacebookGrant?

Comment: Hi, @aod

I will add this class. This is my own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by custom grant but you can use passport service for password grant which can be customized however you like.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#password-grant-tokens

To give more insight, you get a **client_id** and **client_secret** which all users of your api will use to get **access_token** and **refresh_token** using their **password** and **email** as well and then you can customize the process by adding features **via middleware**.

For example you can check some customized header if present or change database based on request to perform further query and so on.

Maybe I got whole wrong idea about your ques, if that's the case then please specify more about your needs.

Comment: We would like to implement social login. Assume that we want to log or register a user in our system by using only a facebook access token. So, we do not have any password or email. PasswordGrant demands password and email. So we have to customize it.